# Resilient s3 notifications

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I have two aws stacks say internal and external

One is used for internal processing and another one is exposed to our clients.

Our client will create files in s3 which is present in external stack. We will not update this external stack frequently.

This internal stack will contain the latest release of our solutions. We will update this internal more frequently like patches, fixes and releases.

We've setup s3 notifications in external stack, which will add an entry SQS which is present in internal stack. An update of internal stack will take minimum of 30 minutes down time for this SQS.

How can we make sure, that we receive notifications for the files that are added in this time period (10 minutes)? Do we have any configuration in AWS to make notifications resilient?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you have down-time of an SQS queue. Do you mean that the service that receives SQS messages will have down time? If so then just make sure your SQS message retention period is set for more than 30 minutes, and the messages will be stored in SQS during your downtime period.

Comment: We will be stopping the whole stack and recreate it. At this time our SQS will be down. Since the SQS queue will be recreated setting retention period on it will not make sense. I want S3 notification to have some retention period or retry mechanism

Comment: I feel like there is probably a much better way to make changes to a production environment than deleting the entire thing and recreating it. However if that's what you are doing perhaps you could send the S3 notifications to a Lambda function that stores them somewhere like DynamoDB if the SQS queue is unavailable. Then you could run something to move those to SQS once your environment is recreated.

Comment: Ok I got it, So there is no way to delay or resend notifications from S3 in case of failure? If that is the case as you've said, we have find a better way to make changes in production. Could you please update the answer accordingly?